After Update to 7.84.14, Artifactory returns 400 on download artifact, which is not on the outer most level of the repo
I updated Artifactory to the latest version 7.84.14 from 7.77.11.
After that I am getting Error 400 when I try to download an Artifact which is not on the most outer level of the Repo.
I suspect it has something to do with Tomcat and the option:
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH
Artifactory is stating that they updated Tomcat in 7.83.1 to 9.0.87 [1]. Tomcat writes they replaced the option with encodedSolidusHandling in 9.0.34 [2]. But i didn't change anything in this regard.
But IDK if it's really the issue, because the Error is pretty useless, and nothing gets logged, other than the request itself:
"GET /ui/api/v1/download?repoKey=ext-maven-ms-local&path=com%252Fgoogle%252Fcode%252Ffindbugs%252Fjsr305%252F3.0.2%252Fjsr305-3.0.2.jar HTTP/2.0" 400 435 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0"

Error in Artifactory UI
Nginx Config
[1] https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-release-information/artifactory-fixed-security-vulnerabilities?tocId=RmN~_12jNg_Wj1Kheh1IwQ
[2] https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html
Maybe someone has the same issue? Or can help me solve it.

Seem like the artifactory.service(Artifactory service installation) does not have all JavaOpts updated properly.
Execute ps -ef | grep artifactory and check if the "-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true" parameter is present.
If not please execute $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/bin/uninstallService.sh(Please check on $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var directory in some os it move var to var.backup with uninstall) followed by executing $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/bin/installService.sh
This will help us to update the artifactory.service will all missing parameters.
The "ps -ef | grep artifactory" should look like this.
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/third-party/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -server -Xms512m -Xmx2g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Djruby.bytecode.version=1.8 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dartdist=docker -Djf.product.home=/opt/jfrog/artifactory -Djruby.bytecode.version=1.8 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start


Thanks it helped. The solution is the missing Java option.
BUT for everyone reading this, be aware that the uninstallService.sh script will mess with your system! It's doing way more then just removing the service. After fixing the mess of the Script i was able to start the System again and its working now.

Tried it on another Testsystem. It's enough to just run the installService.sh over your running instance. It will fix the defaults file which holds the Java Options, and let the rest untouched.
